# Tips on "grouping" similiar data in a grid

Tags: html, css

Hi I am making a schedule (which you can see in the link.) I would like there to be quite a lot more features in the future(obviously.) But as you can see I'm having to create many "repeats"(which i'm actually okay with.) But here's the problem, I can't say "do this to all cells in this row" even though for example, I would like for all mon-jobs to have a "container" that I could act upon and cause all of them to change. Can you please help me with this.

I understand that there's like "Fast creation tools" ill use them in the future. Im more looking for a way to "act upon similiar cells of data, as a group, without compromising their individuality" if that makes sense.

I have tried to create a container but wrapping it in a division that "holds it" but it always causes some error with my grid. Please help me!!!

https://jsfiddle.net/49p0rs2d/

```
#installer-1 {
        grid-column: 1 / 2;
        grid-row: 3 / 4;

    }



#installer-2 {
        grid-column: 1 / 2;

    }

#installer-3 {
        grid-column: 1 / 2;

    }

#installer-4 {
        grid-column: 1 / 2;

    }

#installer-5 {
        grid-column: 1 / 2;

    }

#installer-6 {
        grid-column: 1 / 2;

    }

#installer-7 {
        grid-column: 1 / 2;
        }
```

I would like it to look how it does now. But I would like to be able to act on "groups of ids" For example - All Thursday Jobs or = All jobs of Marks.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you aren't using `<table>`? It seems as though this is achievable very simply with tables. In terms of doing it in the format that you've done, although I highly recommend you use a table, it would reduce your headache by a lot, consider wrapping the jobs for each weekday by doing something like this:

```html
<div id="mondays">
    <div id="mon-job-1"> job-1 </div>

    <div id="mon-job-2"> job-2 </div>

    <div id="mon-job-3"> job-3 </div>

    <div id="mon-job-4"> job-4 </div>

    <div id="mon-job-5"> job-5 </div>

    <div id="mon-job-6"> job-6 </div>

    <div id="mon-job-7"> job-7 </div>       
</div>
```

Then, in JavaScript, if you want to modify lets say, Mark's monday job, you would do something like

```js
const mondays = document.getElementById("mondays");
let markMondayJob = mondays.childNodes[1]
```

This allows you to preserve your current structure and also have 'individuality' for each element. However, I cannot stress enough how much easier this would be in a Table. Instead of having makeshift headings like your codepen does, you could use `<th>` and `<tr>` tags for headings and rows respectively, please consider doing this, will save you a lot of time as you want to have more features in the future!

Comment: Also I forgot to mention, you can basically completely ignore CSS and having to format the grid if you just use `<table>`. It will provide pure functionality and structure, so there will be absolutely no need to worry about grid columns and rows.

Comment: The reason I dont do that is because wrapping it in that div id doesnt work. It breaks the functionality of the grid table try it for yourself